# Conditionally select and insert multiple rows into single row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction how to traverse result set and insert into table without using cursor. Not even sure how to ask this.

Result set of the select query:

```
------------------------------------------------------
ID |  Name  |  CreatedBy  | CreatedDate 
------------------------------------------------------
1     A     John            2018-04-30
1     B     Sam             2018-04-20
2     A     John            2018-04-18
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Inserted table:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID  |  A_CreatedBy | A_CreatedDate  | B_CreatedBy  |    B_CreatedDate |  C_CreatedBy  | C_CreatedDate 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     John          2018-04-30        Sam                   2018-04-20       NULL           NULL
2     John          2018-04-18        NULL              NULL             NULL           NULL
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What will you do with new list? It will be very useless.

Comment: It will help me to show report.

Comment: What if you have multiple rows for a given name and id?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the conditional aggregation as follows:

```
select ID,
       max(case when name = 'A' then createdby end) as a_createdby,
       max(case when name = 'A' then CreatedDate end) as a_CreatedDate,
       max(case when name = 'B' then createdby end) as b_createdby,
       max(case when name = 'B' then CreatedDate end) as b_CreatedDate,
       max(case when name = 'C' then createdby end) as c_createdby,
       max(case when name = 'C' then CreatedDate end) as c_CreatedDate
from (your_query) t
group by ID
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Though I have already tried with aggregation but failed. Getting error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'." .

Comment: @only . . . The subquery needs a table alias which I took the liberty of adding.